# When I click on cancel button unable to reset the lightning input field values?

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
<template>
    
    <div class="slds-m-top_medium slds-m-bottom_x-large">
        <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-m-bottom_medium" >
            Button-icons with the <code>variant</code> attribute omitted or set to the default value of <code>border</code>.
        </h2>
        <!-- with border / by default -->
        <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
            <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:add"  alternative-text="New Request" title="New request" onclick={showModalpopUp}></lightning-button-icon>
            <template if:true={isModalpopupTrue}>
                <!-- //<c-modal-popup-component></c-modal-popup-component> -->
                <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                    <div class="slds-modal__container">
                     <!-- modal header start -->
                       <header class="slds-modal__header">
                          <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={hideModalBox}>
                             <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close"
                                alternative-text="close"
                                variant="inverse"
                                size="small" ></lightning-icon>
                             <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                          </button>
                          <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Leave Request</h2>
                       </header>
                   
                       <!-- modal body start -->
                       <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={objectApiName}
                        record-id={recordId} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
                        <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
                        <lightning-input-field  data-type="user-input" field-name={user}> </lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field  data-type="user-input" field-name={FromDate}> </lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field  data-type="user-input" field-name={Todate}> </lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field  data-type="user-input" field-name={Reason}> </lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-button  variant="brand"  type="submit" name="save" label="Save">
                        </lightning-button> 
                        <lightning-button   name="Cancel" label="Cancel" onclick={HandleResetButton}>
                        </lightning-button>
                        </lightning-record-edit-form>
                             
                       </div>
             
                       <!-- modal footer start
                       <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <lightning-button  variant="brand"  type="submit" name="save" label="Save">
                        </lightning-button>
                          <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={hideModalBox}>Cancel</button>
                       </footer> -->
                    
                    </div>
                 </section>
                 <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
            
            </template>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 300px;">
            <lightning-datatable
                    key-field="id"
                    data={tabledata}
                    columns={columns}
                    hide-checkbox-column
                    onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>
    </div>        
</template>
```

**JS Files >>>>>>**

```
   HandleResetButton(){ 
        console.log('Hit the cacel button $$$$$$');
         const inputFileds  = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field');
          console.log('.....'+this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field'));
         console.log('.....'+this.inputFileds);
         if(inputFileds){
            Array.form(inputFileds).forEach(element => {
                console.log(element);
                element.reset();
            });
        }
```

In console it is showing as undefined.

[image]

How to reset the lightning input field values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.inputFileds` is undefined because you never declared an **instance** variable called `inputFileds`: using [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) you declared a block-scoped **local** variable.

You don't need `Array.from`, you could iterate over a nodeList the same way you can iterate over an array, so you don't need the if block too since iterating over an empty collection doesn't throw an error.

```js
HandleResetButton(){ 
    console.log('Hit the cancel button $$$$$$');
    const inputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field');
    console.log('inputFields size:', inputFields.length);
    for (const inputField of inputFields) {
        inputField.reset();
    }
}
```

Please note that calling `reset()` over a `lightning-input-field` you're resetting the field to its initial values, it doesn't clear the field. [Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/documentation)

If you want to have a blank field, you should set the `value` attribute, while if you want to use the form to create a new record, you should clear the form `record-id` value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the value. This should do it.

```
HandleResetButton(){ 
        console.log('Hit the cacel button $$$$$$');
        this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field').forEach((element) => {
            console.log(element.value);
            element.value = '';
        });
    }
```